# Three digit size N odometer

Tags: python, odometer

I want to generate all possible outputs of a list of size N that acts as a 3 digit odometer.  For example, if N = 4, I want the following output:

0000
1000
2000
3000
0100
1100
...
3332
3333.

Here is my code, any help is much appreciated!

```
odom = [0]*N  ## initialize odometer
print odom
while odom[N-1] <= 3:
    idx = 1
    odom[0] += 1
    if odom[0] > 3:
        while odom[idx] > 3:
            idx += 1
        for i in range(idx):
            odom[i] = 0
    print odom
```

Comment: And what is your question? What's the problem with the code?

Comment: @UnholySheep I think he wants to know how to write a number in base 4. Beyond that I'm not too sure.

Comment: @UnholySheep I am not quite sure how to proceed.  Of course my code does not work but I hope it shows how I am thinking about it.  I want some guidance as I am new to coding.

Comment: Do you want to print all the numbers in that order or as one array?

Comment: @AER I want to modify the odom array and just print it each time, in that order.

Comment: I have worked on it. But so far i can only generate a list of the numbers you need in ascending order and without the leading zeros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(n, digits = 4):
    if digits == 0:
        return ''
    msb, lsb = divmod(n, 4)
    return str(lsb) + foo(msb, digits - 1)

result = []
number_of_digits = 4
maxn = sum(3 * pow(number_of_digits,n) for n in range(number_of_digits))

for n in range(maxn + 1):
    result.append(foo(n, number_of_digits))
```

---

```
result = [foo(n, number_of_digits) for n in range(maxn + 1)]

foo_4 = functools.partial(foo, digits=4)
result = list(map(foo_4, range(maxn + 1)))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Legendary answer. +1 for recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to just use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
for odom in itertools.product('0123', repeat=4):
    print ''.join(odom)
```

If you need to increment the first digit first, you can use `''.join(odom)[::-1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your example doesn't seem to be correct given that it starts by incrementing the first digit by one but it ends by incrementing the last digit by one. Assuming you just want to increase the first digit by 1 in base 4 with 4 digits (change the print if you're using python 2)

```
import numpy as np

def odo(numdigits, maxdigit):
    x = 1
    while len(np.base_repr(x, base=maxdigit)) <= numdigits:
        padding = numdigits - len(np.base_repr(x, base=maxdigit))
        yield np.base_repr(x, base=maxdigit, padding=padding)[::-1]
        x += 1

for x in odo(4, 4):
    print(x)
```

Comment: I think the program must work for N digit numbers. 4 was only an example

Comment: @GeorgeBou You're correct.  Although the code above does work by changing the arguments of the odo function, I am not exactly sure what the function does.  I'll do some research into the contents of the function above.

Comment: @GeorgeBou you can change the parameters in odo: odo(number of digits, base)

Comment: @Normy the generator function just represents the reverse of the number in base 10 (x), and while the base 4 version of x is less than or equal to numdigits in length, it yields the reverse of the number with calculated padding (leading 0s)